# Populate column with the subfolder's name in Python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have written this question focused on pandas since it is a more popular module, to understand a similar example.

I want to add a column and populate it with the part of each files unique address in the directory:

Example:
say I have two files from each subfolder named: `45554` and `32456`
Therefore their paths are like:

```
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INB\INB.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INS\INS.shp
C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INB\INB.shp
```

so I need to extract each rows `-3` position and populate the new column.

Like:

```
   new_col
     45554
     45554
     32456
     32456
     etc..
```

The code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import glob

    folder = path.Path(r"C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE")
        files = []
            for fil in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
                try:
                    files.append(pd.read_table(fil))
                    fil['col'] = shpfile.split("\\")[-3]
                except ValueError as ex:
                    if not os.listdir(fil):
                       print(f'{fil} is empty')
            df = pd.concat(files, sort=True))
            df.to_csv(folder / 'all.csv')
```

How can be achieved?

Comment: Why not append to a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `os` module to perform this manipulation. The benefit of using this module is the correct separator will be used for your platform.

```
import os

x = r'C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INS\INS.shp'

def get_folder(fp, k=5):
    return os.path.split(fp)[0].split(os.sep)[k]

x_folder = get_folder(x)  # '45554'
```

Then just apply within your loop via `pd.DataFrame.assign`:

```
for fil in glob.iglob('**/Desktop/SHAPE/**/' ,recursive = True):
    files.append(pd.read_table(fil).assign(col=get_folder(fil)))
```

Comment: It's a function argument (file path), which can be any input string. I've renamed to fp.

Comment: Why it says: `TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment`

Comment: in this part: `fil['col'] = get_folder(fil)`

Comment: Great improvement. Almost done. It's just that for some values it gives the number as it should but for others it gives the word 'Desktop'. What do you think about it?

Comment: You can move forwards (`k=5`) instead of backwards in case you have different levels, see update.

Comment: Now says: `list index out of range'. I think we should make an `if` where if it isn't numeric it should choose forward or backward and always takes the numeric part of the path. The problem is that although numeric it is read as text.Any ideas?

Comment: For numeric use `int(os.path.split(fp)[0].split(os.sep)[k])`. Sorry, but I need a [mcve] to help more than this.

Comment: I totally understand that this is difficult without the data.

Answer (score 1):

Using `str.split`

**Ex:**

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Path": ['C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SHAPE\\45554\\INS\\INS.shp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SHAPE\\45554\\INB\\INB.shp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SHAPE\\32456\\INS\\INS.shp', 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\SHAPE\\32456\\INB\\INB.shp']})
df['col'] = df["Path"].str.split(r"\\").str[-3]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
                                            Path    col
0  C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INS\INS.shp  45554
1  C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\45554\INB\INB.shp  45554
2  C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INS\INS.shp  32456
3  C:\Users\user\Desktop\SHAPE\32456\INB\INB.shp  32456
```

Comment: I need to do it in a loop and it gives: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
`

Comment: `files['col'] = fil.split("\\")[-3]` This line. Check my code in the question to get more info.

Comment: Try:  `temp = pd.read_table(fil)
temp["col"] = fil.split(r"\\")[-3]
files.append(temp)`

Comment: list index out of range at this part `temp["col"] = fil.split(r"\\")[-3]`